# Why can my Windows 10 minecraft connect to my iPad world, but not the other way around?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a pc with minecraft Windows 10 and i have aan iPad with minecraft PE.  When i make a world on the iPad, i can Join the world with my pc, but when i create a world on pc, and i Wanna join with my ipad im unable to join.

Multiplayer is on in booth cases, and i recieve invites on both devices. Otter players are able to join my pc world, but my iPad isnt. My iPad is able to join other servers.

I think it has something to do with the versions (iPad is 1.13.3 and pc 1.13.1) but im unable to update my pc minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to with the version, it only doesn't work if one version is 1.13 and one is 1.14 or something like that. The reason why you can't update it on your computer is that 1.13.3 is ios only (https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360036461291-Minecraft-1-13-3-iOS-Only-). How does it not work? Does it not display the world or does it display an error when you try to join the world? Try to connenct using both methodes: xbox live and w-land. It might be a bug or have to do with the firewall.